# How to run commands while logging from one machine to another using Expect

Tags: shell, expect

I want to write an expect script which should first login to a Linux machine m1, and then inside m1 it should log in to machine m2. Then in m2, I have to run a few commands.

I tried to use the following script, however here this expect script just runs the command "spawn ssh -X root@$m2". Then it gets terminated without running commands cmd1 and cmd2.

```
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF

set timeout -1

spawn ssh -X root@$m1
expect "assword:"
send  "m1Password\r"
expect "#"

spawn ssh -X root@$m2
#Not given password here because the second machine doesn't ask for a password when logged in via m1.

send "cmd1\r"
expect "Cmd1 Res"
send "cmd2\r"
expect "Cmd2 Res"
EOF
```

How can I improve this script so that commands cmd1 and cmd2 should get run by this expect script?

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to run the second `ssh` within the connection you already opened to machine m1, so you don't need a second `spawn` as this will try to open a new connection from your local machine. So instead of the second `spawn`, use `send` to run the ssh command on m1, and then use `expect` to wait for the prompt on m2 before sending the commands:

```
send "ssh -X root@$m2"
expect "#"
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I also tried this option but I made a mistake in the expect statement. 
I was getting the following output once I logged in to the machine m2:
"root:>". Here, I mistakenly tried to expect for "root" in place of the prompt ">": 
     expect "root"
 Once I updated this statement, it started working properly.